# GetKeyboardState and ToAscii does not always correctly process STX and ETX characters

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard, ascii, keyboard-hook

I am using a global keyboard hook in order to work with a barcode reader. The barcode reader sends an STX character ahead of the barcode and an ETX character after the barcode.

Sometimes the ToAscii function results in the proper STX and ETX codes (0x02 or 0x03), but most of the time it becomes 0x62 (b) or 0x63 (c).

Can this be explained and preferably resolved?

I have added the hook callback below for clarity:

```
    private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            // Prepare the characters and retrieve the keyboard state.
            char[] characters = new char[2];
            byte[] keyState = GetKeyboardState();


            if (KeyPressed != null && WinAPI.ToAscii(lParam.vkCode, lParam.scanCode, keyState, characters, 0) == 1)
            {
                // Initialize the event arguments and fire the KeyPressed event.
                GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs e = new GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(characters, (int)wParam);
                KeyPressed(null, e);

                // Do not call the next hook if the event has been handled.
                if (e.Handled)
                {
                    return (IntPtr)1;
                }
            }
        }

        // Call the next hook.
        return WinAPI.CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many reasons to think of... Please post some code so we can have a clue about the context

Comment: I have added the callback code.

Comment: STX and ETX are common control codes used in serial port communication.  They are not meaningful to a keyboard and you should never pass them to ToAscii().

Comment: Is there some better way of detecting input from the barcode reader, or to detect the STX and ETX without a call to ToAscii?

Comment: Low-level keyboard hooks run on the thread that installed the hook, not the thread that received the keypress. As a result, `GetKeyboardState` returns whether the Ctrl key is down in the thread that installed the hook, which is probably "No." You need to manage the states yourself or use a different type of hook. (Or use some other mechanism for receiving data from the barcode reader. Injected keypresses are really fragile, especially once you have non-English keyboard layouts. Run your program on a Chinese system and things will get very strange.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the scanner is and must be configured as a USB keyboard, I am forced to capture the input using a low level keyboard hook. However, instead of using STX/ETX characters as prefix/suffix, I have now set up the scanner to send a keyboard command (Alt + Shift + Backspace) as prefix and suffix.

This allows me to determine when a barcode is coming and when it has finished. To prevent users from accidentally (or intentionally) oerforming the keyboard command I have implemented a timer. The timer makes sure that barcode parsing is cancelled if no barcode is received after 100 milliseconds.

The keyboard command is caught using the RegisterHotKey and UnregisterHotKey Windows API calls.

When swallowing input during barcode processing it is very important not to swallow the backspace character. The low level keyboard hook is called prior to the hot key callback and swallowing the backspace character will prevent the hot key callback from ever occuring.

Answer (score 0):

The scanner acts as a keyboard but isn't.

By calling the `WinApi.ToAscii`() windows translates the input to a "valid" keymapping. `ToAscii()` interprets 0x02 as the key mapped to 'b'. But that will depend on the current active installed/configured keyboard. So just relying on 'b' & 'c' can cause problems on a... Russian keyboard :-)

Just use the raw input data, extract the data between STX/ETX and map that part to Ascii.
That keycode should be in `lParam.vkCode` or `lParam.scanCode`. [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Result might by like the following, but I'm unable to verify it right now

```
private bool _isScanningCode;

private IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, ref KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            // Prepare the characters and retrieve the keyboard state.
            char[] characters = new char[2];
            byte[] keyState = GetKeyboardState();

            if (lParam.scanCode == 0x02)
            {
                _isScanningCode == true;
                return (IntPtr)1; // act like key is handled
            }
            if (lParam.scanCode == 0x03)
            {
                _isScanningCode == false;
                return (IntPtr)1; //act like key is handled
            }

            if (_isScanningCode)
            {

                if (KeyPressed != null &&
                    WinAPI.ToAscii(lParam.vkCode, lParam.scanCode, keyState, characters, 0) == 1)
                {
                    // Initialize the event arguments and fire the KeyPressed event.
                    GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs e = new GlobalKeyboardHookEventArgs(characters, (int) wParam);
                    KeyPressed(null, e);

                    // Do not call the next hook if the event has been handled.
                    if (e.Handled)
                    {
                        return (IntPtr) 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Call the next hook.
        return WinAPI.CallNextHookEx(hook, nCode, wParam, ref lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: While raw input data would work, it would not allow me to swallow the scanner's input in order to prevent it from being used elsewhere. Also, I do not understand how it is possible that it can both work and not work seemingly randomly on the same PC.

Comment: I am afraid that the approach you are suggesting does not work. The 0x02 or 0x03 are never placed directly in the scan code or virtual key code apparently.

Comment: Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can't configure the scanner to act as a serial device instead of a keyboard?